# Regex printing matches twice in command prompt?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've been writing trying to write to find a particular pattern in all `*txt` files in a given directory. After I find these patterns I'd like them appended to a masterfile.
The pattern is: someletters, number  the code I have is:

```
import re
import glob

pattern = re.compile(",\w\w\w+,\d")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
f= open("masterfile.txt","a+")
    for i, line in enumerate(open(file)):
        for match in re.findall(pattern, line):
            print(match)
            f.write(match)
f.close()
```

Example input file contains:

```
...A,30,35,EHKKDH,6,0.786,Linear
...A,1,7,LKEAELH,7,0.739,Linear
...A,30,35,EHKKDH,6,0.805,Linear
```

Current output is:

```
,EHKKDH,6,LKEAELH,7,EHKKDH,6,EHKKDH,6,LKEAELH,7,EHKKDH,6
```

Expected output is:

```
,EHKKDH,6,LKEAELH,7,EHKKDH,6
```

I get the output I want twice. How do I fix this? I'm sure it's a stupid mistake on my end. I appreciate the help!

Comment: It looks like masterfile.txt is placed in the same directory, wouldn't this lead to each subsequent run to include whatever is in the masterfile.txt? This looks like it could be the cause for your issue.

For the future, please make sure your code is correctly indented for readability purposes

Comment: I apologize. It's fixed now. That was exactly the problem! I didn't think about the subsequent runs including whatever is in masterfile.txt. Thank you for your help!